# two domains, one server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

`/etc/apache2/conf.d/virtul.conf` :

`NameVirtualHost *`

In the first file of `sites-enabled/website1.org` you'll see a group such as:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName website1.org
</VirtualHost>
```

And the same for website2.org

The domain (and subdomains) located in website1.org work exactly how they should. However, nothing works for website2.org. When visiting website2.org in a browser I get a `500 Internal Server Error`

Two notes:
1) When running `# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` I get:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                [Tue Jul 24 09:31:59 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost 72.10.54.89:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting [Tue Jul 24 09:32:00 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost 1.23.456.769:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

2) website2.org has an ssl cert and that ssl VH is set up as `sites-enabled/website2.org-ssl`

FYI yes I ran `a2ensite` for every domain, followed by an apache `reload` and after all were setup I did an apache `restart`.

What can I do to get my second website live? I'm not sure what to check next.. Thx for help.

** edit @RedFoxy **

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                   [Tue Jul 24 10:56:57 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:57 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:57 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:57 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:57 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:57 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost 72.10.54.89:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:57 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting [Tue Jul 24 10:56:58 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:58 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:58 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:58 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:58 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:58 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost 72.10.54.89:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Tue Jul 24 10:56:58 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Comment: And you have an IP for each website or you want them served on the same IP address?

Comment: Good point. Everything is name based on the same IP.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just you must specify the port as:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website1.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Remember to change :80 with the web port that you need

Comment: I don't think that's allowed because the format is not `*:80` since one of the sites is `:443`. It didn't fix the problem anyway.